# 'Compressor()' has private access in 'id.zelory.compressor.Compressor' en android studio como solucionar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
import id.zelory.compressor.Compressor;

public class CompressorBitmapImage {
    public static byte[] getImage(Context ctx, String path, int width, int height) {
        final File file_thumb_path = new File(path);
        Bitmap thumb_bitmap = null;

        try {
            thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(ctx)
                    .setMaxWidth(width)
                    .setMaxHeight(height)
                    .setQuality(75)
                    .compressToBitmap(file_thumb_path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumb_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,80,baos);
        byte[] thumb_byte = baos.toByteArray();
        return  thumb_byte;
    }
}
```

Tengo un problema con el compresor de imágenes para mi app en `Android Studio` al correr mi app me manda un mensaje un error: `'Compressor()' has private access in 'id.zelory.compressor.Compressor'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes utilizar una dependencia vieja ya que la actual por problemas de compatibilidad
con las nuevas versiones esa linea de codigo no funciona,en el build gradle
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.1'